# Fetching products by category slug using the Doctrine "Tree" extension

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, nested-set-model

I currently have `Product` and `Category` entities, with a many-to-one relationship through the product's `category` property. The category has a slug defined using the `@Gedmo\Slug` annotation, which is working perfectly.

Unfortunately the [Tree extension's documentation on Github](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) is fairly brief when it comes to slugs, especially selecting by them. I've tried quite a number of Google results but haven't been able to find a solution yet.

What I'd like to know is, how I can fetch all products that are within a given category slug, **or** within a child category of that slug?

Can anybody help please?